# How to display user input safely in HTML?

Tags: asp.net, html, user-input

Suppose I have a textbox on my ASP.net web page where a user enters some text.

On another page, I have the following: `<p><%=userText%></p>`, where userText refers to the text that the user entered on the previous page.

What do I need to do to make the text display properly if it contains special characters? Also, users can enter text that will be displayed to other users, so it is imperative that I prevent abuse (such as injecting `<script>` tags.

Comment: sanitizing user input is one of the easiest tasks to do, as long as you don't need anything special. As soon as you want to allow the user to add elements to the page, the problem becomes significantly harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should HTML encode the data, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx).

```
String TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```